# Writing an expanding array

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have a piece of code that waits for data to come from a shaky network. The machine that runs the code could also go down at any moment.

So I am writing in-coming data to the disk as the program runs. If the system goes down, I would have data up to that point. I can save each data object in a separate JSON file but that would end up with hundreds of thousands of files.

What I would like to do is to append to one JSON file that can be read back as an array or list. Each time the data comes in it is written to the end without re-writing the older data. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Sounds like you need a [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `FileWriter`, with `true` as the second constructor argument.  This makes a `FileWriter` that will append to an existing file, instead of replacing it (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

Answer (score 0):

The method does not change the value of OrigArray; all it does is store a clone of a clone in it, so in effect the value isn't changed.

I think what you want is this:

```
public void expand() {
    String[] newArray = new String[OrigArray.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(OrigArray, 0, newArray, 0, OrigArray.length);

    //an alternative to using System.arraycopy would be a for-loop:
    // for(int i = 0; i < OrigArray.length; i++)
    //     newArray[i] = OrigArray[i];
    OrigArray = newArray;
}
```

This creates an array that has a size 1 greater than OrigArray, copies the content of OrigArray into it and assigns that array to OrrigArray. Unless you want to remember how many times expand() has been called, there shouldn't be a reason to have the variable size.